Any JGit DFSRepository implementation with database
I am experimenting with creating a JGit DFSRepository implementation with a database. From what I understand so far, I need to implement DfsObjDatabase, DfsRefDatabase.
So far I have started implementing the DfsObjDatabase. It seems the Jgit framework first calls the newPack method which returns the DfsPackDescription, and then it calls writeFile. I am guessing I need to implement the writeFile(DfsPackDescription desc, PackExt ext) to insert the pack file in database through sql. Not sure why this method return DfsOutputStream?
Are there any example implementation of database backed JGit DFS implementation?
